# How to bulk insert with derived columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

**Newbie to SQL Server!**

I try to perform bulk insert into SQL Server. I have the following csv file named `input.csv`:

```
NO,Name,age,Reference,dateTime,Category
1,Stack@mail,23,Kiop,2017-03-02T12:23:00,D
2,OverEnd@Yahoo,22,CSK,2017-030-03T12:23:00,I
```

In that CSV file, I have to move that into SQL Server using `BulkInsert` into below table schema:

```
create table BulkInsertTemp
(
     no int,
     name nvarchar(50),
     age int,
     Ref nvarchar(30),
     currentDatetime datetime,
     Category nvarchar(40)
)
```

Now I need to store in SQL like:

```
no Name    age   Ref    currentDatetime        category
--------------------------------------------------------
1  Stack    23   Kiop   2017-03-02 12:23:00       D
2  OverEnd  22   CSK    2017-03-03 12:23:00       I
```

I just tried below query for another one table to move into SQL Server.

```
create table bulkInsert(no varchar(50),name varchar(50));

BULK INSERT bulkInsert 
FROM 'C:\MyInput\BulkInsert\BulkInsertData.txt' 
WITH 
    (FIRSTROW = 1, 
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
     ROWS_PER_BATCH = 10000)
```

My query worked if there is no need for modifying data.

But in `input.csv` I have to change column values such as **if name is "Stack@mail" to be store as "Stack" in SQL**

I am a new one to bulk insert option so I don't know how to derive columns from existing ones.

Anyone, please guide me to solve my requirement?

Comment: you could bulk insert the original values into a temp table first and then copy them (insert ... select) from there to your real destination table ... while selecting from the temp table you could do any transformation you need ...

Comment: `BULK INSERT` is optimized for maximum speed - but by doing so, it sacrifices some flexibility and does **not** offer any way of manipulating / transforming / changing data when inserting. Use the approach @PrfctByDsgn has outlined - insert into a staging table "as is" (no manipulations, no changes etc.), and *then* do whatever you need to do to your data once it's in SQL Server

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions let me try

Comment: I have one doubt regarding my csv file is in one machine but SQL runs in another machine.In this category bulk insert will work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend building an SSIS package to do this. If you don't know how or don't have time you could run the [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052(v=sql.105).aspx) which will actually create an SSIS package for you behind the scenes.

Hope that gets you going in the right direction.

Noel